# Forma mais indicada de alternar classes de APIs ativas num sistema?

Tags: php

Seguinte, Nesta aplicação existe um módulo de envio de Sms que possui diversas APIs diferentes, todas seguem um mesmo padrão base, implementam os métodos obrigatórios da interface Sms, algo assim:

```
interface Sms {

    function setNumber();

    function setMessage();

    function Send();
}

class smsEmpresa1 implements Sms () {
    ...
}

class smsEmpresa2 implements Sms () {
    ...
}
```

E no controller, a API ativa é chamada através de um valor salvo no banco de dados:

```
switch ($sms_ativo) {

        case '1':
            $sms = new smsEmpresa1;
            break;

            case '2':
            $sms = new smsEmpresa2;
            break;
    }

    $sms->setNumber('xxxx');
    $sms->setMessage('yyyy');
    $sms->Send();
```

Só que dessa forma não existe uma padronização, o número da API é definido de forma manual, e toda vez que se cria uma nova classe é necessário adicionar no switch, qual seria a forma mais indicada de se fazer isso?

Comment: $sms_ativo é sempre o número da empresa contido no nome da classe?

Comment: Sim, um número que vem do banco de dados e eu escolho manualmente